# Can not connect from flutter app to java backend running on Google Cloud Run

Tags: java, docker, flutter, google-cloud-platform, jetty

I have deployed a java backend in a docker container running on Google Cloud Run, now am having connection issues. I can reach my java backend using chrome and postman, but not flutter.

I am connecting to it using a flutter app. My java backend uses Jetty embedded for http. Previous to this, I did development on my local machine, and in the flutter app I would hard code in my servers LAN IP. The client connected reliably in this scenario

I have since deployed to Google Cloud Run and am not able to connect to the backend with my client.

I have tested the docker container locally, and I was able to connect to my backend when running the container using this command...

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 --network="host" image1
```

In the google cloud run console, I set the port to 8443.

In my flutter app. I have changed the URL from...

```
https://192.168.100.103:8080
```

To the url the Google Cloud Run specifies as my IP (I then added the port)...

```
https://blahblah-82j3flsijf-uc.a.run.app:8080
```

My flutter code that establishes the connection is as follows...

```
        HttpClient client = HttpClient();
        client.connectionTimeout = Duration(seconds:2); // throws SocketException after timeout
        client.badCertificateCallback = ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true); // find the way to specifically accept a self signed certificate

        HttpClientRequest request = await client.getUrl("https://blahblah-82j3flsijf-uc.a.run.app:8443");
        request.headers.contentLength = requestBody.length;
        request.write(requestBody);
```

My java backend code that establishes the jetty http server is as follows....

```
            Server server = new Server(8080);

    HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
    handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[]{ new MessageHandler(), new DefaultHandler()});
    server.setHandler(handlers);

    server.start();
    server.join();
```

When I try to connect from my flutter client, I get http 400 bad request.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue. I had a few problems here.

First was that I was using https encryption in my java app when Google Cloud Run takes care of that for me. So I disabled https in my java app. I assume Google Cloud Run requires your container to handle only http requests (not positive though).

Secondly, I changed all my ports to run the Google Cloud Run default of 8080, and then completely removed the port from my flutter url.

Thirdly, I was calling HttpClient.getUrl which performs an http GET, but I was also adding a request body to the get. You should not add a body to a GET request. This previously worked for me because both my jetty based java backend, and the flutter dart:io HttpClient are completely fine with this violation, and both worked with a GET with a body. As soon as I introduced Google Cloud Run layer, it introduced more stringent enforcement of the http protocol, and correctly returned bad request when I sent a GET with a body.

If you are adding a body, use dart:io HttpClient.postUrl.